# log4cxx: sending log to log server?

Tags: log4cxx

We have a single threaded application and has to remain single threaded for some reasons. We have a large volume of runtime debug log using log4cxx. What's the best way to do the logging without impact the performance of the application?

I know log4cxx can send log to
* local files directly. This can slow down the application quite a lot. Profiling already confirmed this.
* sending to local syslog. I suppose that this may not be much different from sending to local files directly.
* sending to SocketAppender. I tested using log4j's SimpleSocketServer. The performance is no better than writing files directly. I haven't looked at source code for SimpleSocketServer. The most naive implementation is that SocketAppender is using blocking write, while SimpleSocketServer uses blocking reads from socket and only do next read when it finished writing current log entries. This will perform the same as logging to local file directly.

I guess that we'll have to write a logging server, with 1 threading reads from socket and put the msg on the queue and another thread writes the msg to log file.

There is likely such a free logging server somewhere on the internet. Before start searching for such a server or write one ourselves, are there any other solutions?

Thanks.